# Hey 10kers... you also have the delete votes

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

Well, the users with 10,000 reputation or more has access to the moderation tools (commonly referred as 10k-tools) which give more insight over the site itself. There's also the infamous flag queue that has its number fixed besides the review link. But they also have delete votes, and this is what I want to talk in this post.

Well, there are a couple of closed, old, abandoned and bad questions that someway or another received enough views or votes that aren't getting deleted by Community ♦. I know tracking them down is a hassle but while cleaning up tags (I wonder when I will stop) I found questions that either are not worthy of being reopened or the current scope of the site doesn't allow us to reopen them. I voted to delete them accordingly but then reviewing the [Delete queue](https://askubuntu.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days) I've seen several days old posts. How about if we delete them? I know mods can do this but hey, we should be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, when you use these delete votes, it can be helpful in letting moderators know which NAA flags to handle as "delete" much quicker :)

Comment: well, I was talking about question... 10k users can't delete answers ;)

Comment: I forgot which rep level can vote to delete answers... thought it was 10k

Comment: I've noticed people don't seem to downvote even non-answer answers very much, even while flagging them. My informal (possibly wrong) impression is that about 10% of NAA-flagged posts get negative score. Even for 20k users, delete voting is only possible on negative scored answers. Maybe people don't realize that their -1 downvoting rep (as well as the post author's -2 rep) is reversed when the answer is deleted.

Comment: @EliahKagan about that, I was doing it, but then I noticed that the answers weren't getting deleted as fast as they should and I had to keep a list of Q/A that I would like to upvote or downvote for the next UTC day.

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Downvoting NAA answers is something to do in addition to flagging them, not instead of flagging. If you're out of votes but flag an answer, and the flag is judged correct (in the sense of being worth actioning), it will still get deleted, usually before you get more votes. Keeping track of answers you've flagged but weren't able to downvote is fine, but not really necessary.

Comment: @EliahKagan at first I added a DV to the flag, now I just flag NAA's since I need to cast votes on good, bad and wrong posts. The NAA's flags/delete votes doesn't get handled promptly by 20Kers but I need the votes when I find a post useful.

Comment: @EliahKagan This problem should be going away soon as the 10k flag queue gets removed and the flags get pushed to the low quality post queue. As an aside, I am supposing that your downvote doesn't count?